# Could not find JSON-RPC

Tags: objective-c, brightcove

Error when creating playlist with Brightcove's Media API in objective c:

```
{"method":"update_video","params":{"video":{"id":"myID","economics":"AD_SUPPORTED"},"token":"myToken.."}}

{"name":"MissingJSONError","message":"Could not find JSON-RPC.","code":211}, "result": null, "id": null}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to send the JSON as form data rather than as the raw post body. This works, but I'm not an objective c expert.

```
NSString *urlString = @"https://api.brightcove.com/services/post";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSString *data = @"json={\"method\":\"update_video\",\"params\":{\"video\":{\"id\":\"myID\",\"economics\":\"AD_SUPPORTED\"},\"token\":\"myToken..\"}}";
[request setHTTPBody:[data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseData bytes]];
NSLog(@"%@",content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to send the JSON as "multipart/form-data" rather than as the raw "application/json" post body.

My HTTPClient:

```
private static async void GetStatus2()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                string refId = "5e6c4d61-554c-42cc-ac34-cf3f3c5ba36d";
                string writeToken = "ueBq0azalcY3KhCxNPsiGyv-aH4kOQUxpm5YXX6vsT2DIE9W3d5MPQ..";

                var statusRequest = new GetStatusRequest(refId, writeToken);
                var statusRequestStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(statusRequest);


                //Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"
                var stringContent = new StringContent(statusRequestStr);
                stringContent.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"JSONView\"");
                //stringContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;");


                content.Add(stringContent, "json");


                var message = client.PostAsync("http://api.brightcove.com/services/post", content);

                var input = message.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HTTPGetStatusResponse>(await message.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response));
                Console.Read();
                if (response.result == HTTPGetStatusResponse.UploadStatus.ERROR)
                {
                    var ex = string.Format("BrightCove Api Error! Error Code: {0}. Error Name: {1}. Error Message: {2}", response.error.code, response.error.name,
                                           response.error.message);
                    throw new Exception(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```